# Vista search replacment?

Tags: windows-vista, search, windows-search

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [What search utilities can search by file name in Windows 7?](https://superuser.com/questions/209231/what-search-utilities-can-search-by-file-name-in-windows-7)

Is there any way to replace the vista search function with the windows XP search assistant/tool ?

Comment: Whoa. Kinda like "Is there any way to throw away our civilization and go back to the stone ago?" :-)

Comment: i'm afraid this puppy is history. :)

Comment: The last living remnant of Microsoft Bob ... passed away :-)

Comment: And tell me WHY you'd want to do this?

Comment: @ephilip I can speak of many people in my office who hate the vista search mechanism and want the old XP one back

Comment: Why?
Simple: Because the search assistant worked, although he was slower.

Comment: Vista's works much better than XP's ever did.

Answer (score 3):

Best search I've ever found is here at http://www.voidtools.com/ programs named "Everything". super fast indexing and has never slowed me down once since installing on my windows vista machine. I recently installed it on a windows 7 machine and it worked perfectly. I have disabled my windows indexing and this has been perfect for any on the fly search.

Answer (score 1):

You might be interested in something like [Locate32](http://www.locate32.net/) or [Google Desktop](http://desktop.google.com/).

Comment: gogo gadgets from google

Comment: i already have locate32, unfortunately the annyoing thing on locate32 is that updating the index takes soooo long, and then you still can't search for text in the file. That, google can, but google slows down the system too much.

Comment: You want XP's search back, and you're complaining locate32 takes time? ;)

Comment: Correct. You see, there's a massive difference in time in a live search through a few directories, as compared to indexing the entire drive...

But yes, locate32 is fast, unfortunately, latest additions to the filesystem only show up once you update the index (15 min)