# What search utilities can search by file name in Windows 7?

Tags: windows-7, software-rec, search, windows-search

I've just installed Windows 7 64-bit and have found that it's file search really really sucks.  What is a good alternative that I can load on my system to do file searching?

Note: I don't care about text searching in the file.  I just want to search by filename.

**EDIT:**  To sum up what is mostly in the comments:

- [Agent Ransack](http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home) - Has a [big bug](http://www.mythicsoft.com/kb/JunctionPoints.ashx) in it, that's really limits its usefulness.  Their fix doesn't work, and its been out there a few years.
- [Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) - Doesn't have very many options, and really sucks when trying to search in a specific path.
- [Fileseek](http://www.fileseek.ca/) - Now has a way to get around the recursive loop problem

Comment: Agent Ransack is not as good a choice, when compared with Everything.

Comment: @harrymc, That was just the one I chose to use now (acceptance is an individual thing), BUT I figure on trying Everything later, and I'll change my Accept then.  If you had specific details to edit into Mehper's answer that would be great.

Comment: Maybe consider using a more objective description instead of 'sucks' to make this a better question/answer for future users. why does windows search not fulfil your needs?

Comment: @Jaips, it doesn't really work at all for finding files like the old XP search (which could also have been improved).  The Windows 7 search was really made for text searching.

Comment: @Lance Roberts, If you use 'filename: %query%' in the search box you can search by file names only, though i agree in windows 7 (and vista) its much less discoverable than it should. See http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/b182ea87-0764-474a-8fb3-f188e0840ff5 . Is this what you mean?

Comment: @harrymc, After finding a big bug in Agent Ransack, I moved to Everything.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: could you elaborate what kidda bug you've found in Agent Ransack and was it an error or just an annoying behaviour of the program?

Comment: @BerggreenDK, see the link I posted in the Agent Ransack answer below.  I haven't had time to implement it yet, but it describes my problem perfectly.

Comment: Windows 7 search drives me nuts! Why are there LESS features than Windows XP?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

### [FileSeek](http://www.fileseek.ca/)

(Freeware by Binary Fortress Software)

> FileSeek is a lightning fast, small and easy to use file searching
>   application for Windows. It can even be integrated right into the
>   Windows Explorer right-click menu to provide quick and easy access.
>   FileSeek doesn’t use background indexing, so when FileSeek is closed
>   your computer’s performance won’t be affected.
>
> FileSeek works with 32-bit and 64-bit versions of Windows 7.

Comment: Wow, I'm in love, especially since with my SSD drives I don't want to run background indexing.  I'll run it through its paces this next week.

Comment: @Lance Roberts: Nice to know you like it. Please drop a few lines here about your upcoming experience.

Comment: While I'm still using this it has one bug where you can't use "C:" as the path (always returns no answers), you have to use "C:\", and even then you get a bunch of Error messages.  It still works great if you know the next directory down and search from there.

Comment: This is nowhere near as fast as Everything. Everything is in an instant. and Everything does regex. I've just got Fileseek to search filenames only (you leave the query field blank and choose search type of match full string), It has taken 30 seconds so far to look for WMV files and hasn't found any yet. Everything finds a bunch within a second and with a regex wmv$ so flexible too.

Answer (score 35):

[Everything](http://www.voidtools.com/) is what I use. Very fast and handy.

Comment: It's a pity that it does not run on normal user accounts though.  I would have liked to have used it on domain accounts, only searching through user files.

Comment: pure awesome. Took about 45 seconds from download to usage. +50 rep for this.

Comment: @Crazy, Beware that I've now found that Everything does not let you choose the path you want to search, very frustrating when dealing with multiple drives, some networked.

Comment: I guess most small and cheap programs arent really meant for commercial usages nor testet on such.

Comment: Everything does let you choose the path you want to search. Read the doc.

Comment: +1 for Everything.  It's dirty fast, but a little inconvenient for network shares.

Comment: @harrymc, yes I've found that if you type the path in by hand, in quotes, then it will search for it.  It will also work if you right click on a folder, but there is a bug where if you right-click on a Drive to search, the syntax comes out wrong, and you have to fix it by hand.  I'm always searching on my C: drive, so that's not very functional for me.  It'd also be nice if they had a dropdown/browse capability to choose the path.

Comment: @LanceRoberts  Apparently The newer version has unary operators including http://webcache.googleusercontent.com/search?q=cache:XnmHXCTEVOkJ:support.voidtools.com/everything/Search_syntax+voidtools+everything+syntax+search&cd=1&hl=en&ct=clnk&gl=uk  or http://support.voidtools.com/everything/Search_syntax    file: and  folder: and other unary operators i.e. ability to specify files and folders specifically.

Comment: @barlop, thanks, it's time to give it another try, I still haven't been happy with anything yet.

Comment: @LanceRoberts report back

Comment: @barlop, you have to load the alpha version to get the unary operators to work, but they don't appear to have a full install package, just an executable, so no way to test the right-click context menu stuff.

Comment: Too bad it *still* doesn’t support FAT32 volumes.

Comment: @Synetech  I think the whole magic with its instantaneous search, is thanks to a feature of ntfs, ntfs journalling or something, not found with fat32.

Comment: @barlop, actually, all it does is to enumerate all files on the disk (all together for the first time, then periodically update thereafter). Then it has a complete file listing (I believe it skips certain locations), which makes it easy to find files by names, size, date, etc. In fact, I occasionally use `dir` to get a complete file listing of my volumes and can then find a file in seconds. They have been promising a FAT32 version in the FAQ for years, so they obviously have something in mind.

Comment: @Synetech  Try scrolling down to Mehrdad's answer, he mentions SwiftSearch, a program he wrote. I don't know if it supports FAT32, but it may be trivial for him to add it. You could comment there. BTW, why do you use FAT32?

Comment: @Synetech  Also, if you don't know how to write a program with a GUI, have you ever thought of writing a script to do it? or try vworker/rentacoder.

Comment: @barlop, yes, I use FAT32 almost exclusively because it lets me boot into DOS and use Norton Disk Editor to directly access the file-system at a low level for things like data-recovery. I only use a couple of of NTFS volumes for Windows 7 and a 4.37GB DVD ISO scratch disk. As for programming, there’s no need to reinvent the wheel. There are plenty of programs that can already do this; it is simply a matter of finding the best one(s) by trying them (all?) or soliciting feedback from those who have tried them (hence this question).

Answer (score 14):

Windows 7 search is actually not all that bad once you learn some key words.

Windows 7 search uses [Advanced Query Syntax](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=VS.85%29.aspx) 
(more options described [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb266512%28v=vs.85%29.aspx))

It sounds like you want to do some very basic search functions. Here are some examples.

The following searches for files larger than 8 MB with a name containing the text "filename", having the extension .mp3 and having been modified on the 25th.

```
name:~~"filename" size:>8 MB ext:.mp3 datemodified:7/25/2011
```

The double tilde searches for any part in the search string containing your search term. It is like doing a search for "*someSearch*" using the wildcards below. If you don't use the double tilde, it will only search the beginning of words.

For example, doing a search for `name:"file"` or `name:"ness"` when the filename is `"Aewsomeness Somefile.txt"` would not show up unless you had the double tilde since those search terms are not at the beginning of words.

You can also use wild-cards like in the good old days (the single tilde lets you use the older style wildcards (? and *):

```
name:~"f?lena*"
```

The "?" is a place holder for any one character. The "*" is a place holder for any number of any characters.

Comment: Thanks for the info.  I read through the AQS link you had, but it didn't explain what the tildes and double-tildes were for.

Comment: @Lance Roberts The second link (Using Advanced Query Syntax Programmatically) describes the double and single tilde under the "Query Operators" section. I updated my answer with more details on tilde and double tilde.

Comment: a +1, The syntax becomes second nature once you get used to it, and built in solutions are always preferable.

Comment: I submitted an edit to fix the link to the Advanced Query Syntax reference. Use this now: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=VS.85%29.aspx

Answer (score 9):

[Google desktop](http://desktop.google.com/)

Comment: Well, I installed it, didn't get to really test out its search capabilities before it ticked me off because the `close` function in the menu for the sidebar didn't work.  While I thought I'd love the sidebar, there are times that I would need to close it (and I really hate the work ethic of the lazy programmer who put the line in the menu but didn't make it work).

Comment: Some time ago, I used Google Desktop. It was way too heavy. If you use it, you will probably notice slowdown.

Comment: Since it works during idle-time - slowdown is imperceptible... firewall and AV make more feasible affect )

Comment: -1 [Google desktop has been discontinued ](http://googledesktop.blogspot.com/)

Comment: Very funny )) Don't you think that it's been a long time since the answer was given?)

Answer (score 6):

```
cd where.to.start.searching && dir /s /b *part.of.filename*
```

Comment: yes, the good old Command Prompt - but if you want to search fast, then you should consider to place these in a .CMD file with search critieria as parameter

Answer (score 5):

I've always liked [Agent Ransack](http://mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=agentransack&page=home), one of the best free file search utilities out there. You can search for file names or file contents and it has lots of other options such as boolean operators. It also comes in 32 or 64 bit.

Comment: It also lets you save searches for future use.

Comment: also known as filelocator lite http://www.mythicsoft.com/page.aspx?type=filelocatorlite&page=home

Comment: Agent Ransack has a lot of options, but one big bug (in Windows 7 64-bit).  It does some kind of recursive loop search on the directories and returns 20 or 30 results instead of 1, with the paths just recursively becoming larger.

Comment: Here's [the link](http://www.mythicsoft.com/kb/JunctionPoints.ashx) to fix the Agent Ransack bug.

Comment: Agent Ransack is excellent. It will find any file that exists on the drive. If you don't search so often that you need indexing, or only search specified locations, use it. If kept open after a search, later searches are faster. But its big brother, the non-free FileLocatorPro, is a better choice if you want indexing. Then Windows indexing can be turned off.

Answer (score 5):

Since I've used [Everything Search](http://www.voidtools.com/), I haven't cared where I save my files anymore. Everything even looks inside the Recycle Bin.

- Regular expressions on filenames work.
- You can search only specific paths by [adding the path to the search string](http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php#How_do_I_search_for_files_and_folders_in_a_specific_location), e.g. "ctures\ *.jpg" for images in any user folder.  The path cannot have wildcards though.
- Its FAQ provides [instructions](http://www.voidtools.com/faq.php#How_do_I_bypass_the_UAC_to_run__Everything__with_administrative_privileges_on_system_startup) on bypassing the UAC prompt. It's real unfortunate that ES hasn't updated in almost two years to add this scheduled task automatically or during setup. Well, just do this setup once and forget about it.  Running it in startup is actually advised, because ES startup takes a few seconds in large file sets.
- Just a tip: So ES won't slow the system down, if you have a background process that creates hundreds of temp files in a certain path, exclude that path.

Comment: There are some nice features there, though the path stuff doesn't work well, in fact if you right-click on a drive and select `Search Everything` it comes up with the wrong syntax.  What they really need is choices like Agent Ransack has in combination with their search capabilities.

Comment: Hi @lance-roberts, in four years of using it, I've never tried right-click>Search Everything. I've always used a hotkey to open ES (no UAC prompt!) and I always type a "\" to restrict the search to paths. That drive letter behavior is indeed strange, so use "c:\", "c:\ *.jpg" or "c|d|e:\ *.jpg" instead. But Lance you gotta admit that you love ES's results-as-you-type, and that its background indexing is very lightweight and barely noticeable. I see that CrazyJugglerDrummer is convinced, so what else are you looking for?

Comment: Yeh, I do like their quick results.  One disturbing thing I've seen is that when I don't get results, I left wondering if it's still thinking, there's no indication that I've noticed telling me of the Fail.  I'll be exercising it more over this next week, and see how it goes.

Comment: The said hotkey is Win-G, by the way. In the said four years, I also tried Google Desktop, [X1](http://www.x1.com) and [Copernic](http://www.copernic.com). I always end up back to ES. :)

Answer (score 4):

Not an answer to your direct question but:

You can search by file name in windows search using the special syntax 'filename: %query%' in the search box. Though its probably fair to say this is much less discoverable than it should be. See [this post](http://social.answers.microsoft.com/Forums/en-US/w7files/thread/b182ea87-0764-474a-8fb3-f188e0840ff5) (microsoft forums).

Answer (score 3):

[Cygwin](http://www.cygwin.com/)

Then, `find / -name "Name of file"`. I don't have much experience with Windows command line searching but the `find` utility ever fails me. Again, a batch/bash script file would make this an easy way to use a powerful search.

Comment: I admin some Unix systems and have to use find a bit, though not enough that I always remember the funny syntax.

Comment: The good thing is you could write a small batch file with the command already in it. I admit that the syntax is a little tricky but this is a good path for you to explore and maybe learn. The utility is extremely powerful (you could even combine it with something like grep/egrep) and the time spent learning it would definitely save time searching down the road.

Comment: Yeh, I like batch files and try to use them when I can, I'll have to think about this one.  Does Cygwin have `diff` in it also?

Comment: Yeah cygwin has GNU diff

Comment: You don't necessarily need Cygwin. Gnu find is also included in the GnuWin32 package (http://gnuwin32.sourceforge.net/). But in any case, it might be a good idea to rename the exe to gfind.exe or similar, so it doesn't clash with the Windows `find.exe` (which is something like a lame `grep`)

Answer (score 3):

### [FileSearchEX](http://goffconcepts.com/products/filesearchex/index.html)

> FileSearchEX is the no nonsense file search utility for Windows 7. It
>   offers the simplified search interface like Windows XP yet in an
>   updated and modern fashion. Unlike other search tools, FileSearchEX
>   works well with millions of items in the result pane.
>
> - Low system requirements.
> - Extremely simple search interface.
> - Portable application for easy network deployments.
> - Millions of search results can easily be navigated.
> - Users don't need to learn a new file search utility. XP style
>     search.

[image: screenshot]

FileSearchEX is *free* for personal use on a personal computer.

Comment: I like this one too. They just updated it with some more features.

Answer (score 3):

You can try the search with command prompt. Very few people know about this.

[Command Prompt Search](http://www.funbutlearn.com/2012/08/the-easy-way-to-search-files-search.html)

Answer (score 3):

I use Lookeen myself. It is an Outlook tool but can be used as a [Windows Search](http://www.lookeen.com) solution as well. Unfortunately it is a bit expensive. But there I found a test demo. You should try it.

Answer (score 2):

[Super Find XT](http://fsl.sytes.net/ssearchxt.html) is another one.

Comment: I downloaded and installed this today, but to even change the filename (or path) you have to have the 'supporters' version, so I can't even test it.

Comment: There is also a startup bug (in Win7 64bit) where it's looking for some unknown drive.

Answer (score 2):

### [Locate32](http://locate32.net/)

(Freeware by Janne Huttunen)

> Locate32 is software which can be used to find files from your
>   harddrives and other locations. It works like updatedb and locate
>   commands in Unix based systems. In other words, it uses databases to
>   store information about directory structures and uses these databases
>   in searches. The use of these databases provides very fast searching
>   speed. The software includes a dialog based application as well as
>   console programs which can be used to both update and access
>   databases. Supported operation systems are Windows
>   98/ME/NT4/2000/XP/Vista/7.

Answer (score 2):

### [XSearch](http://www.easexp.com/xsearch/)

(Freeware by www.easexp.com)

> XSearch is a classic search tool with more features Windows Search
>   does not provide. It works in classic way: no indexing service keeps
>   scanning your files continuously in background.
>
> It supports to search for files by file name, size, date time and
>   words. Unlike in Windows Search, you can specify the exact size (Byte,
>   KB, MB or GB), the exact date and/or time, and the different date time
>   (Modified, Created, Last Visited).
>
> You can specify the word or file name options such as "Any", "All",
>   "Exact phrase", "Without" etc., and case sensitive, hexadecimal value,
>   UTF8 and Unicode.
>
> The HexView tool included in XSearch allows you to view files in
>   hexadecimal, it acts like a read-only editor, and supports large
>   files.
>
> Supported OSes: Windows 2000/XP/Vista/2008/7

Comment: A HexView tool sounds enticing.

Comment: Such a nice tool. All others don't work without admin rights... This should be the selected answer.

Answer (score 1):

Install Cygwin and do Unix-style searches with find, grep, et al.

Answer (score 1):

#### Try a program I wrote a couple of years ago: [SwiftSearch](https://sourceforge.net/projects/swiftsearch/)

It only works for an admin account, and only for NTFS.

#### **Update:** I just open-sourced it! *(see updated link)*

Comment: Actually, I'm always running an admin account.

Answer (score 1):

I am a real fan of Windows "Classic search" from 2000/XP, so for me EaseXP's free [XSearch](http://www.easexp.com/xsearch/) utility fills that gap on my Windows 7 x64 PC. It has a nice explorer-like results pane where you can manipulate the found files (open/cut/copy/delete, etc). However, I've experienced capricious application faults with XSearch; when this happens I tend to fall back to [Astrogrep](http://astrogrep.sourceforge.net/), which despite its name, can do file name only searches, and has seen some active development this year. I'm also leaning towards using [Nirsoft's SearchMyFiles](http://www.nirsoft.net/utils/search_my_files.html), which has useful duplicates and non-duplicates search modes, as well as a standard search mode.

To expand on a previous `CMD.EXE` solution, you could put the following in your `CMD.EXE` startup script, if you have one. (the full path to your startup CMD script needs to be defined in `HKEY_CURRENT_USER\Software\Microsoft\Command Processor\AutoRun` registry key).

```
doskey f=dir /s /b "$*"
```

Example usage:

```
f D:\installers\*.msi
f C:\Documents and Settings\win*
```

Answer (score 1):

## [FileSearchy](http://www.filesearchy.com/)

> FileSearchy is a quick, powerful and easy to use utility to search files on your computer. It provides real-time search by file name. Unlike other search tools with instant file search, it also allows searching by content string, date and size. FileSearchy supports many popular formats and highlights found text in file name and contents.

Free for personal use.