# Windows 7 cannot find a file "hello world -20110519.rmvb" when the keyword 20110519 is used, WHY?

Tags: windows-7, windows

There is a file in a folder.  The filename is:

`hello world -20110519.rmvb`

and I tried to use the keyword `20110519` but no result is found.  I think in 1980, computer was in really basic stage, and it is now 30 years later, and Windows 7 still cannot do something simple like this correctly, I am fairly disappointed.   Why is the search not successful and what channel can this be sent to the Windows 7 team so that this bug can be fixed?

---

**Update**: if the file was `hello world -20110519.txt`, then the search will find the file.  So the file extension matters?  This must be the peak of civilization such things can happen.

Comment: first 3 times I really Needed the w7 search, 2 of those it did not find files that I had with odd extentions. I of course tried some of the options to change it LOLOLOL. In folder options , there are a few things to change the search, good luck. it did not help me because i had already changed them.  Organise - Folder and Search Options - Search Tab.

Comment: Check out: http://superuser.com/questions/209231/what-search-utilities-can-search-by-file-name-in-windows-7

Answer (score 0):

I would check my regional setting and make sure Windows doesn't think `20110519` is a date.

Because in some parts of the world, like China, that is a valid date (Year, Month Date).

Try typing `name:20110519` into the search box.

**edit**

Made a file

[image]

Now with Search.

Maybe check that **partial matches** is checked under the Tools menu in file explorer?

[image]

Now with a weird extension. . .

[image]

Comment: wow, the computer nowadays is so smart that you have to do a "time / region" management before you do a search huh?

Comment: I can't fault Windows for guessing that is a date. I **do** fault Windows for **not showing other matches** when it was an implicit date query.

Comment: Try it yourself -- for the file `hello world -123456.rmvb` -- Windows 7 again cannot find the file using the keyword `123456`.  Are you saying Windows 7 is so smart to try to interpret `123456` as a date?  Then rename it to `12345` and it won't work again.  And `12345` is a date?

Comment: I tried it and it worked.

Answer (score 0):

Where is the file located? Are you searching indexed folders? If the folder that the file resides is not indexed by search, typing it in the search box will not yield any results. Try telling it to search your entire computer.

My favorite way of brute forcing a search in Windows is using the command prompt. Run `cmd.exe` and then go to the root directory by typing `cd \`. Then type `dir/s *20110519*.*` and hit enter. It should find the file. If it doesn't, then it doesn't exist.

**EDIT:**

I just tried this myself by placing a file named `hello world -20110519.rmvb` in `C:\test` and then did a search and it came up. So I am not sure what's going on, in your case. If you did this and you aren't seeing the same thing, then I don't know, sorry. Screenshot below:
[image]

Comment: try it in `c:\try` or something... as I said, if the filename has the extension `.txt` then it will be found.  If the extension is `.rmvb` then it won't be found.  Then would indexed or non-indexed matter?

Comment: You have to do it from the root directory (`c:\`). If you search from `C:\try`, unless it's under that directory, it will not find it. dir/s will go through all folders and subfolders in that directory. Searching using this method will ignore indexed settings. Did you follow my instructions exactly?

Answer (score 0):

I can't reproduce this, which leads me to suspect it's an issue with your file and not a general Windows Search issue. I have problems like this from time to time where certain files won't properly appear during a filename search.

Windows Search has gotten many facelifts over the years and it's still not great.

I'd suggest doing the following to narrow down what the cause is:

1. Move that file to another directory and try the search again
2. Rename it to something else and see if you can find it in a search
3. Create a new text file and name it the same as your .rmvb

Depending on what happens, you can tell if the file is somehow unsearchable (sounds like a bug or at best poor user education on Microsoft's part), Windows isn't returning *any* .rmvb files in searches (must be a setting somewhere), or something else.

To be honest, if you need decent search on your local machine, Google Desktop is still the way to go. It's not as convenient as the search bar built into Windows Explorer, but it finds things very effectively.

Comment: Note that there is a space before the `-` and no space after it

Comment: Yes, I entered it with the space. It had no bearing on the search working or not. Whatever the issue with your search it, it's not related to a "magic" filename. What happens if you rename the file to test.rmvb? If it shows up in search I'd be baffled.