# search for a substring in file name with built in windows search

Tags: windows, search, windows-8-preview, file-search

I am using windows 8 and I find that the built in search facility is not working as expected.

I have a folder like this

[image]

and when I search it like this, I get no result.

[image]

I would like the search tool to have matched on the partial file name.[This question](https://superuser.com/questions/209231/what-search-utilities-can-search-by-file-name-in-windows-7) provides a good workaround, but ideally I would like to have this working out of the box. Is there a setting to change or any other means to get partial file search match without installing additional software?

Comment: Your screenshot cannot be read at all. Can you upload somewhere else?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Short answer: Use * (asterisk) or ~~ (double tilde). In order to search for a substring in the file name you must put the `*` or `~~` in front. Hence, in order to have Windows find the `MyFile.txt` you must search for `*file*` or `~~file` and not `file`. Think at `~~` as `containing`.

The simple form (without asterisk) *searches only at the beginning of the words* in file name. Hence searching for `file` will return `File.txt`, `My File.txt`, `File 1.txt` (aso.) but will not return `MyFile.txt`.

If you want the complete(?) Advanced Query Syntax have a look [here](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/aa965711%28v=vs.85%29.aspx). However I do not see in the AQS page linked the `*` (any number of characters) `?` (just one character) and `[ ]` (set of characters) wildcards.

Examples:

- `b?r` matches `bar` and `bur` but not `boor`
- `b[ae]r` matches `bar` and `ber` but not `bur` or anything else

Comment: Is there a way to change this behavior? This same method is used in Win7's start menu search. So if I want to select and launch FireFox I want to just type 'ff' and it should show up...(at least that's how it works in Launchy and OSX's spotlight)