# Why does "dir *.*~" list files in a way different to what is expected?

Tags: windows-7, command-line, dir

In my directory I have the files files

- x.dll
- x.lib
- x.pdb
- x.exp
- x.plugin

When I issue the command `dir \*.*~` it should say 'File not found' as it does at my friend's laptop. But on my machine it lists the file `x.plugin`.

Actually after a while of trying I found out that it lists all files with extension longer than 3 characters.

Anybody heard about this behavior before?

Comment: This is Windows 7 you are using?

Comment: yes it is. and it must be quite a new behavior, as it used to work correctly (means only files like x.bak~ being returned for the supplied wildcard)

Comment: Windows 7 extends the way you can use wildcards (check [this answer](http://superuser.com/a/314721/25438)). But adding a tilde (`~`) at the end doesn't seem supported, so the result may be undefined, as you're getting. Adding it at the *beginning* of the query should tell Win 7 to use DOS style syntax for wildcards (but the tilde itself will be ignored).

Comment: @Groo: AQS does not seem to be supported at all by the dir command though.

Comment: XP I just get file not found. Even when extension is over 3 char. And even when there are files starting with ~ , and even when there's a file with both features ~df.adfdfd  it says File Not Found. What even caused you to do dir *.*~  ?

Answer (score 1):

Seeing the command `dir *.*~`, I would assume it lists *all* files in the directory.

The `*` placeholder means 'any number of any character'.

If you want to find all files ending in  `xx~`,  I would use the command `dir *.??~`. The '?' means 'any one character'.

At least, this used to be so in the 'old' DOS days...

Comment: this used to work - and still it works on my friend's machines *.*~ returns all files who's extension ends with '~' - this means, lists all backup files which for example jEdit creates

Comment: @rezna does your friend have a different cmd.exe ? like a different size? (as the dir command is within that file), so i'm wondering if he has a different dir command.